# How to update Dell Alienware BIOS without battery?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, bios, battery

I tried to update the BIOS for my Alienware M17xR4 but it doesn't work due to my battery being dead (6yo battery).

The flash tool dell provides is called InsydeFlash, I tried to temper the parameters.ini to remove the AC verification but it doesn't work (the software always create a new version of the parameters.ini when you start it), I even tried to put the parameters.ini in Read only, but then, InsydeFlash doesn't open at all.

I tried commands like `/forceit` `/writeromfile` `/writehdrfile` etc... nothing worked so far, the only think I didn't try was installing the BIOS via flashdrive, but then, I can't extract the BIOS from Dell's InsydeFlash tool.

This is the driver page (Version A15): https://www.dell.com/support/home/br/pt/...?driverid=wy72t

Mine is still at A11, I am trying to update the BIOS in order to solver a GPU problem, it's status is Faulty on windows drivers, but when I run ePSA Built-in Diagnostics from Dell, every test on the Video card is normal.

How should I proceed? I can't update the BIOS at all and I am not willing to afford another battery.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Never heard of such behavior. It's normal to force the power supply for obvious reasons but check for battery with the AC connected? It seems nonsense to me.

Comment: Yeah, "weird" enough, dell will advise you to buy a new battery to update your system bios, despite the fact I have an alien face in my screen instead of a bitten apple... haha